# flake8, only on diff and exclude

Tags: git, pep8, flake8

I'm trying to run flake8 in a pre-commit hook on only the changed files in my git diff, while also excluding files in my config file.

```
files=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM);
if flake8 --config=/path/to/config/flake8-hook.ini $files; then
    exit 1;
fi
```

I'm essentially wanting to do:

```
flake8 --exclude=/foo/ /foo/stuff.py
```

And then have flake8 skip the file that I passed in because it is in the exclude variable.

I'm also wanting it to exclude files that are not .py files. For example:

```
flake8 example.js
```

Right now as I'm testing, neither of these work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: flake8 can do essentially everything for you: http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/using-hooks.html

Answer (score 15):

If what you're after is running flake8 on both uncommitted and staged python files with changes, this one-liner will do the trick:

`flake8 $(git status -s | grep -E '\.py$' | cut -c 4-)`

git status lists the changed files, grep for python, get rid of the M / S bit at the beginning with cut.

To make it into a pre-commit hook, you need to add the shell hashbang:

`#!/bin/sh
flake8 $(git status -s | grep -E '\.py$' | cut -c 4-)`

Save it as .git/hooks/pre-commit, chmod +x.

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to your questions:

## 1. Running flake8 in a pre-commit hook on only the changed files in my git > diff

For running `flake8` on only diff files (which have been staged), I modify the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` script to as follow:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH  
export files=$(git diff --staged --name-only HEAD)  
echo $files  
if [ $files != "" ]  
then  
    flake8 $files  
fi
```

I am using the `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` as I generally commit from sourceTree, which does not pick up the path where flake8 resides

The `--staged` option allows only the files in staging area to be picked up

For the second, part:

## 2. excluding files in my config file

You can create a `.flake8` file in you repository root that can take care of this. My `.flake8` file looks like this:

```
[flake8]  
ignore = E501  
exclude =  
        .git,  
        docs/*,  
        tests/*,  
        build/*  
max-complexity = 16
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `flake8` to check files before commit, simply use

```sh
flake8 --install-hook git
```

ref: https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/using-hooks.html

Comment: `usage: flake8 [options] file file ...
flake8: error: unrecognized arguments: --install-hook` ;  check the ref

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use `flake8` as a pre-commit hook, [this article](https://lmy.medium.com/make-any-code-linter-report-incrementally-8398afdf51cb) walks you through how to write a glue script that filters the analysis result for findings that are only on the lines modified.